# Cannot end processes with taskkill, get "the system cannot find the file specified" error

Tags: windows-7, command-line, tasks

Whenever I run the following in a command prompt:

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
```

I get an error saying "the system cannot find the file specified".

I've tried that command without the `/f` option, and with other processes, but get the same result. I've researched the error message but haven't found anything useful.

How can I fix this? Alternatively, is there another way to kill processes from the command prompt?

I'm running Windows 7 Home Basic 32-bit, only doesn't work on netbook.

Tasklist gives the same error, and I've read somewhere that tasklist is not avilable in the Home Basic edition, so can the same be true for taskkill as well? Although I can see that both taskkill and tasklist executables exist in the system32 folder.

Comment: Did you run sfc /scannow (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833 )

Comment: I solved this by adding  C:\Windows\system32; at the start of PATH in environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Win7 Home Basic, but if taskkill.exe and tasklist.exe don't exist in Windows\System32, just use [**PsKill**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) instead (also available as part of the [**PsTools Suite**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx)).

Comment: i ll try pskill now, but those files do exist...
ok pskill worked, thank you very much !

Comment: If they do exist, then [check the PATH environment variable](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) and confirm that Windows\System32 is the very first directory specified.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that your `PATH` environment variable is not set correctly. Run `echo %PATH%` in Command Prompt, and if the output does not include `C:\Windows\system32`, then that is your problem.

To fix:

- Go to **Start Menu**
- Right click **Computer**
- Click **Properties**
- Click **Advanced System Settings**
- In the **Advanced** tab, click **Environment Variables**
- Under **System Variables**, find **PATH**
- Click **Edit**
- Put `C:\Windows\system32;` at the start of **PATH**
- Click **OK** and **Apply** until you are out of everything
- You may need to reboot your computer for the changes to take effect

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`Taskkill` is not available in Windows XP/7 Home edition.

Instead you can use `tskill` which is available in all Windows editions.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the windows standard task manager can easily do what you ask.

Comment: i know, but i need to do it from cmd

Comment: In the future please include all revelent information in your question so that you get an answer appropriate to your situation.